# Any risk in providing bank account number routing number along with name and DOB?

Tags: scams, checking-account, job-offer

I applied to a remote job on indeed North America (job listing had Louisville, KY as location), and overnight , without interview, they gave me an offer letter saying I was selected and I'll be a part time assistant manager, and job was to go to super markets and snap pictures.
And they sent me a document in which I was supposed to fill   , to get started on job.

- **   bank name  (they specified only chase, BoFa , Wells Fargo and US Bank )
- bank account number,
- routing number ,
- full name and
- date of birth.    (they didn't ask for ssn)
- phone number**.

The document has a one line company address based out of Buenos Aires Argentina. It has company logo on all pages, no letter head nothing.
But the guy who sent me email said the office was in Sweden but none in US and gave one address. I google that address it shows some other company name.

If I were to provide my 
**full name date of birth and Bank account + routing number**, and in case it turns out to be an elaborate scam,
can the miscreants wreak havoc like steal from my account , make purchases or sell my info on the deepweb/darkweb/darknet/whatever  , ??

I looked at : [Is it safe to give out one's bank account number?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/is-it-safe-to-give-out-ones-bank-account-number)
 and http://www.nbcnews.com/id/7914159/ns/technology_and_science-security/t/easy-check-fraud-technique-draws-scrutiny/#.WnudiHWnEYM   but that didn't satisfactorily answer my question.

I called my bank (bofa) thrice, each time I was put on hold for >1hour and call got disconnected.

PS: 
In 2015, after signing up for one vpn (private internet access) and connecting to it via my mobile phone, my entire bofa checkings account was emptied in less than an hour with purchases being made all over the world.

Bofa gave me my money after a week. ^

Comment: This is a scam. This is clear from the fact that you are offered a job with no followup. Nothing else matters. Be aware of scam warning flags, and don't worry about *how* such a scam might work. If you are being scammed, there is asymmetry of information - the scammer knows everything, and you know only what you can deduce yourself. So rather than go into your specific questions, it is better to simply say "No, this is a scam" and walk away. See related answer for more: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/88217/44232

Comment: It is indeed a scam, may I ask which company is it, also are you allowed to post the letter here?

Comment: "in case it turns out to be an elaborate scam"  It's not really all that elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

This is all information that is needed to perform a direct deposit to your bank account (with the possible exception of the date of birth).  So a legitimate business might ask you for this information.  That said, there are some reasons to think that this is a scam.

1. They limit the banks where the account can be.
2. They made a hire offer without an interview.
3. You can't confirm their business address.
4. They don't seem to be asking for the required employment information.  In particular, employers need proof of citizenship.

In terms of how the scam might work, if you're lucky, they'll just write themselves a check on your account.  If you're unlucky, they have a way to borrow money to your account and withdraw it.

If you really want to pursue things, tell them that you need to be paid by check.  A legitimate business shouldn't have a problem with that.